# SQL ContainsTable is ranking higher if word is found multiple times. How do I stop this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

We have a procedure that returns this:

```
SELECT TOP 15 SearchName, AlternateName, CountryName, StateProvince, Latitude, Longitude, Type, boost + k.Rank as Rank
FROM SearchLocations
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([SearchLocations], [SearchName], @Search) AS k
    ON SearchLocations.Id = k.[Key]
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

Basically, it full-text searches `[SearchLocations]` and orders the results based on full-text ranking and the boost column. Problem is, when I search for `ISABOUT("L*" WEIGHT(1.0))', which is what would be given to '@Search' as the input for "L", cities like

- Lagos Lagos Nigeria
- Lima Provincia de Lima Peru

show up higher than `Los Angeles California United States`. While their boost is lower, full-text search gives them a higher ranking because they repeat the same word. This also happens in cases of places that don't repeat words but have the same sub-word multiple times.

How do I disable/work around this?

Comment: If boost is not what you want to rank by, can you explain exactly what you do want to rank by?

Comment: Boost gives preference to larger cities and locations in the US. It is supposed to be a supplement for how well the text matches the query (which is given fairly well by `k.Rank` from the fulltext search query).

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm for the full-text index being used by SQL Server is very heavily weighted to give more occurrences of a text match a better rank (bumping them up higher in your results).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142524%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> **CONTAINSTABLE ranking uses the following algorithm**:
>
> StatisticalWeight = Log2( ( 2 + IndexedRowCount ) / KeyRowCount )
>
> Rank = min( MaxQueryRank, **HitCount * 16** * StatisticalWeight / MaxOccurrence )

AFAIK this algorithm is completely internal and can't be modified.

As a workaround you *might* be able to change what the indexer considers "words" and get SQL Server's full-text indexer to ignore spaces between words - so "L*" only gets a `HitCount` of 1 against "Lima Provincia de Lima Peru" instead of the 2 it gets now, thus lowering the place in the rankings to what you want.

If you want to try it: [View or Change Registered Filters and Word Breakers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207002.aspx)

But then you'll be losing much of the value of full-text search so **I don't recommend this**.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to implement the same algorithm without hitcount with something like `LIKE` or `CONTAINS`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just order by the `boost` column:

```
SELECT TOP 15 SearchName, AlternateName, CountryName, StateProvince, Latitude, Longitude, Type, boost + k.Rank as Rank
FROM SearchLocations
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([SearchLocations], [SearchName], @Search) AS k
    ON SearchLocations.Id = k.[Key]
ORDER BY boost desc;
```

You don't have to order by the `rank` just because you are using `CONSTAINSTABLE()`.

Comment: We encountered problems with that as well. For example, `Mount Rushmore` didn't show up even though it's SQL Rank was 480 and everything else was 60.

Comment: I like this approach, but with a couple changes so rank is still useful. MaxRank from ContainsTable is 1000 - so if the `boost` numbers are scaled to be about the same you might get the result you want e.g. `ORDER BY (boost * 10) + k.rank`